# Give a computation of the expression to normal form (Lambda calculus)

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus

Past exam question:

[image]

What my understanding of B-reduction is : Find all occurrences of the parameter in the output, and replace them with the input and that is what it reduces to

```
(λ param . output)input => output [param := input] => result
```

Example:

```
(λx.xy)z

= (xy)[x:=z]

= (zy)

= zy
```

But I do not know how to use B-reduction on the expression above. What is the input, output and the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, a series of applications $f\,x_1\,x_2 \dots$ means $\big(\big((f\,x_1)\,x_2\big)\,\ldots\big)$. We say that *application is left associative*.

According to this convention, there is an extra set of parentheses that is implied in the expression you write. Here I've made it explicit:
$$\big((\lambda f.\lambda g.\lambda x. f \,(g\,x))\,(\lambda u.u)\big)\,(\lambda v.v)$$

The expression $(\lambda f.\lambda g.\lambda x. f \,(g\,x))$ is a function and it is applied on input $(\lambda u.u)$. Reducing this will result to a function of the form $(\lambda g. \lambda x. \langle\text{body}\rangle)$, which in turn gets applied to $(\lambda v.v)$.